# How to design nested class properly?

Tags: c#, linq, class, dataset

I generate 2 class looked like this :

```
public class mPromotionDetail
{
    public long PromotionDetailId { get; set; }
    public long PromotionHeaderId { get; set; }
    public long PromotionTypeId { get; set; }
    public string PromotionTypeName { get; set; }
    public string VendorCode { get; set; }
    public string VendorName { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public List<mPromotionDetailArticle> RequestDetailArticles { get; set; }

    public static List<mPromotionDetail> Get(long PromotionDetailId = 0, long PromotionHeaderId = 0, long PromotionTypeId = 0, string VendorCode = "", bool Active = true)
    {
        try
        {
            Hashtable htParam = new Hashtable();
            htParam.Add("@PromotionDetailId", PromotionDetailId);
            htParam.Add("@PromotionHeaderId", PromotionHeaderId);
            htParam.Add("@PromotionTypeId", PromotionTypeId);
            htParam.Add("@VendorCode", VendorCode);
            htParam.Add("@Active", Active);

            DataSet ds = DB.ExecuteSP_Ds("udsp_GetPromotionDetail", htParam);
            return ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(row => new mPromotionDetail
            {
                PromotionDetailId = row["PromotionDetailId"],
                PromotionHeaderId = row["PromotionHeaderId"],
                PromotionTypeId = row["PromotionTypeId"],
                PromotionTypeName = row["PromotionTypeName"],
                VendorCode = row["VendorCode"],
                VendorName = row["VendorName"],
                Active = row["active"],
                RequestDetailArticles = mPromotionDetailArticle.Get(PromotionDetailId: Shared.NtL(row["PromotionDetailId"]), Active: true)
            }).ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}

public class mPromotionDetailArticle
{
    public long PromotionDetailArticleId { get; set; }
    public long PromotionDetailId { get; set; }
    public string ArticleCode { get; set; }
    public string ArticleDescription { get; set; }
    public long Qty { get; set; }
    public string UoM { get; set; }
    public decimal NormalPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal SpecialPrice { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    public static List<mPromotionDetailArticle> Get(long PromotionDetailArticleId = 0, long PromotionDetailId = 0, long PromotionHeaderId = 0, bool Active = true)
    {
        try
        {
            Hashtable htParam = new Hashtable();
            htParam.Add("@PromotionDetailArticleId", PromotionDetailArticleId);
            htParam.Add("@PromotionDetailId", PromotionDetailId);
            htParam.Add("@PromotionHeaderId", PromotionHeaderId);
            htParam.Add("@Active", Active);

            DataSet ds = DB.ExecuteSP_Ds("udsp_GetPromotionDetailArticle", htParam);
            return ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(row => new mPromotionDetailArticle
            {
                PromotionDetailArticleId = row["PromotionDetailArticleId"],
                PromotionDetailId = row["PromotionDetailId"],
                ArticleCode = row["ArticleCode"],
                ArticleDescription = row["ArticleDescription"],
                Qty = row["Qty"],
                UoM = row["UoM"],
                NormalPrice = row["NormalPrice"],
                SpecialPrice = row["SpecialPrice"],
                Active = row["active"]
            }).ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that `ExecuteSP_Ds` is just calling my SQL SP and returns `DataSet`.
This works just fine. But if `mPromotionDetail.Get` returns many rows (ex: 1000 rows), it means `mPromotionDetailArticle.Get` will be executed just as much time.

Is there any way to design this more properly and efficiently?

Thank you

Comment: You should read about design patterns, solid principles, those are good places to start.

Answer (score 0):

You could start by decoupling your database code from your entities, some good, and tested ways to do it are by using some of the following patterns:

- DAOs
- Repositories

For further research I recommend you to read this article:
[MSDN - Persistence Patterns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd569757.aspx#id0400052)

There it also speaks about Lazy and Eager loading, that way you could minimize the workload and size of your database call.

Finally it be good for you to read about the SOLID Principles, some good places are:

- [Scotch.io SOLID](https://scotch.io/bar-talk/s-o-l-i-d-the-first-five-principles-of-object-oriented-design)
- [Solid Principles Succintly](https://www.syncfusion.com/resources/techportal/details/ebooks/solidprinciplessuccinctly)
- [Solid Using C#](https://www.syncfusion.com/resources/techportal/details/ebooks/solidprinciplessuccinctly)

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking hundreds/thousands of rows on your call to these procs, consider having the procs take paging parameters (e.g. pageNumber, rowsPerPage). Then modify your proc to use this paging parameters. You can search in SO about how to apply paging in your queries.

Your other option, is to have your proc return multiple results sets and then just do the object mapping of your master-details data in the code.